# How to sort on a variable within each group in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to sort a value `val` using another column `ts` for each `id`.

```
# imports
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession as ss
import pandas as pd

# create dummy data
pdf = pd.DataFrame( [['2',2,'cat'],['1',1,'dog'],['1',2,'cat'],['2',3,'cat'],['2',4,'dog']] ,columns=['id','ts','val'])
sdf = ss.createDataFrame( pdf )
sdf.show()

+---+---+---+
| id| ts|val|
+---+---+---+
|  2|  2|cat|
|  1|  1|dog|
|  1|  2|cat|
|  2|  3|cat|
|  2|  4|dog|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Couldn't you just pass multiple arguments to `sort()`? I'm fairly certain that `sorted_sdf = sdf.sort('id', 'ts')` will achieve the desired result, without having to aggregate and explode.

Comment: Yes, `sort` would technically work for the dummy data here.  For my actual use case, however, I need to expose the intermediate steps and carry out some additional procedures.

Comment: Also, `sort` is more expensive if you don't need `id` sorted, correct?

Comment: I can't say with 100% certainty, but it seems like it would be less expensive than partitioning, collecting a list, sorting the array, and exploding.

Comment: Hmm, but even so, those things are more parallelizable than a global sort, to my understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can aggregate by `id` and sort by `ts`:

```
sorted_sdf = ( sdf.groupBy('id')
                  .agg( F.sort_array( F.collect_list( F.struct( F.col('ts'), F.col('val') ) ), asc = True)
                  .alias('sorted_col') )  
             )

sorted_sdf.show()

+---+--------------------+
| id|          sorted_col|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|  [[1,dog], [2,cat]]|
|  2|[[2,cat], [3,cat]...|
+---+--------------------+
```

Then, we can explode this list:

```
explode_sdf = sorted_sdf.select( 'id' , F.explode( F.col('sorted_col') ).alias('sorted_explode') )

explode_sdf.show()

+---+--------------+
| id|sorted_explode|
+---+--------------+
|  1|       [1,dog]|
|  1|       [2,cat]|
|  2|       [2,cat]|
|  2|       [3,cat]|
|  2|       [4,dog]|
+---+--------------+
```

Break the tuples of `sorted_explode` into two:

```
detupled_sdf = explode_sdf.select( 'id', 'sorted_explode.*' )

detupled_sdf.show()

+---+---+---+
| id| ts|val|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|dog|
|  1|  2|cat|
|  2|  2|cat|
|  2|  3|cat|
|  2|  4|dog|
+---+---+---+
```

Now our original dataframe is sorted by `ts` for each `id`!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, it indeed helped me. Is there a more elegant way to chain all those functions instead of `F.sort_array( F.collect_list( F.struct( F.col('ts'), F.col('val') ) ), asc = True)` ?

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks.